# How do I change this.state of a component from parent?

Tags: reactjs

I know, in ReactJS I can pass down a state to a component.

Parent jsx:

```
<Display active={this.state.dispActive} />
```

And use it in the child jsx render like this (example):

```
<div>Display: {this.props.active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}</div>
```

But when I try to have this in the child's own state, it doesn't work:

```
state = {
    isActive: this.props.active
}
```

Probably the state is initialized in the constructor once and then not changed.

I want to call a function here, in the child, when the state of the props changes. Only way I found around this was including all the child's code into parent and then pass the state down as a result of the code

Parent:

```
handleDisplayChange = (e) => {
    //Code here then use this.setState to change parent's this.state 
    //which then reflects on the passed props in the child
}
```

But what if the child includes some kind of a library that not belong in the parent logically and I want to lets say set a certain attribute of that object **in the child**?

```
this.display = new Display();
this.display.setActive = this.state.isActive
```

this.display is constructed in the child. It doesn't belong in the parent's context. I need

1. a function in the child that sets this.display.setActive
2. set this.state.isActive of the child itself.

That would not belong in Parent.jsx because parent is supposed to place the display in one jsx constructor and a button toolbar in the other:

```
<div className="App">
    <Toggle toggleState={this.toggleState} active={this.state.dispActive}/>
    <Display active={this.state.dispActive} />
</div>
```

Edit: Pasted the wrong code, edited to make more sense.

Comment: You can use componentDidUpdate() to detect changes

Comment: @ShoebMirza I tried this but it doesn't work. In fact it works but always one step too late. ReactJS seems to update the child's jsx and then run did update to change the state. I click on toggle, display says "Active" but this.state.isActive in child still says false. After second click, this.state.isActive changes to true but display supposed to be inactive by now. this.state.isActive always one step back.

Comment: Can you update with the `componentDidUpdate` part that you have tried?

Comment: You can send function from your parent.js to your child component and trigger from child

Comment: @ShoebMirza correction, I tried it with componentWillUpdate(). Component did update works. However only when I check if this.state.isActive !== this.props.active before otherwise I get an maximum update depth error.

Comment: I don't really see the point of updating the `state` of a child element, when you can use `props`

Comment: @ShoebMirza to your second comment, yes I already have that in my original question (see handleDisplayChange) but I don't want to use that here as described because I don't want to hold this.display = new Display() in the parent because it doesn't belong there.

Comment: @GalAbra because the child's state supposed to hold a flag if this.display.setActive was set to active.

Comment: If I understand your question properly that your parent component is updating state but you are not seeing the changes in your child component?

Comment: @ShoebMirza no. I want to trigger **a function** in the child that calls this.display.setActive **in the child** and additionally keeps the current state of isActive in it's own state context. It needs to be **in the child** because this.display is created there and not in the parent where it doesn't belong.

Comment: I edited the question to make this more clear

Comment: Can the Parent not pass a `setActive(true/false)` to the child? Then the child does not need to have it's own `active` state and just keep using the prop passed from Parent.

Comment: @HMR I edited my question to make it more clear what I need: I need to call a function in the child on state change.

Comment: You wrote that your child state is not working properly like state = {
    isActive: this.props.active
} what value are you getting when you print this.state.isActive in your child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to call a function in the child on state change.

You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` function for this. Inside this function you can check if props or state changed. If any one of the two changed, you can call whatever function you want to call in child component from `shouldComponentUpdate` function

**Example**

assume that function `foo` is the one you need to call in child component when state or props change. You define `foo` function inside child component and then also define `shouldComponentUpdate` function inside this child component

```
class Child extends Component {
  state = {
    isActive: this.props.active
  };

  foo() {
    console.log('function called when state or props change');
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (
         this.props.isActive != nextProps.active || 
         this.state.isActive != nextState.isActive
    ) {
        this.foo();   // call function on state or props change
        return true;
    }

    return false;
  }


  render() {
    return <p>{this.state.isActive ? 'active' : 'not active'}</p>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the question, you pass active from Parent that can be toggled by Parent to a Child where active can also be toggled by Child. If that's the what you need then I don't see why Child needs to be stateful:

```js
function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        parent
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={e => setActive(a => !a)}
          checked={active}
        />
      </label>
      <Display active={active} setActive={setActive} />
    </div>
  );
}
function Display({ active, setActive }) {
  //can set active from child as well based on
  //  any logic you want
  return (
    <label>
      child
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={e => setActive(a => !a)}
        checked={active}
      />
    </label>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, a parent can pass down props to the child but not the other way. In your case, you are passing state to the child via props. Received props cannot be modified by the child. You can achieve what you want by having a function to handle side effects in the parent then pass it down as a prop to the child and trigger it from child based on circumstances you would want the state to be updated.

The solution is to pass a function from the parent to child. This function will update the parent state, and because you are passing the parent state to the child, it will also be updated.

`i.e you can pass a function as a prop to the child component, so the child component can call this function to update the parent component, then call this function in child passing in updated state.`

Comment: Yes please see my original question: handleDisplayChange in parent could do that but it doesn't belong there.